# Moveit : moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup group("right_arm")

Tags: ros, moveit, pr2, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i was going through the Moveit tutorials:

```
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup group("right_arm")
```

there was this error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

What must be the problem:-?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250728/moveit-:-moveit::planning_interface::movegroup-group(%22right_arm%22)/) by [Abhinav Sonone](https://answers.ros.org/users/28155/abhinav-sonone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2016-12-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> What must be the problem:-?

you forgot to compile the C++ sources of the "Moveit tutorials" that you didn't link us to?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0